# grep regex to pull out a string between two known strings

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I have a string of text in a file that I am parsing out, I almost got it but not sure what I am missing

basic expression I am using is

```
cat cred.txt | grep -m 1 -o '&CD=[^&]*'
```

I am getting a results of

```
&CD=u8AA-RaF-97gc_SdZ0J74gc_SdZ0J196gc_SdZ0J211
```

I **do not want the `&CD=` part** in the resulting string, how would I do that.

The string I am parsing from is:

```
webpage.asp?UserName=username&CD=u8AA-RaF-97gc_SdZ0J74gc_SdZ0J196gc_SdZ0J211&Country=USA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `grep` knows Perl regex:

```
grep -m 1 -oP '(?<=&CD=)[^&]*' cred.txt
```

If not:

```
sed '1s/.*&CD=\([^&]*\).*/\1/' cred.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to skin this cat.

Extend your pipe:

```
grep -o 'CD=[^&]*' cred.txt | cut -d= -f2
```

Or do a replacement in sed:

```
sed -r 's/.*[&?]CD=([^&]*).*/\1/' cred.txt
```

Or get really fancy and parse the actual QUERY_STRING in awk:

```
awk -F'?' '{ split($2, a, "&"); for(i in a){split(a[i], kv, "="); out[kv[1]]=kv[2];} print out["CD"];}'
```