# Parsing HTML on the command line; How to capture text in <strong></strong>?

Tags: perl, sed, awk, grep, command-line-interface

I'm trying to grab data from HTML output that looks like this:

```
<strong>Target1NoSpaces</strong><span class="creator"> ....
<strong>Target2 With Spaces</strong><span class="creator"> ....
```

I'm using a pipe train to whittle down the data to the targets I'm trying to hit.  Here's my approach so far:

```
grep "/strong" output.html | awk '{print $1}'
```

Grep on "/strong" to get the lines with the targets; that works fine.

Pipe to 'awk '{print $1}'.  That works in case #1 when the target has no spaces, but fails in case #2 when the target has spaces..only the first word is preserved as below:

```
<strong>Target1NoSpaces</strong><span
<strong>Target2
```

Do you have any tips on hitting the target properly, either in my awk or in different command?  Anything quick and dirty (grep, awk, sed, perl) would be appreciated.

*Update:* I appreciate the suggestions to use a proper HTML parser or tool for scraping.  However, at the time I was working on this, the process running the script didn't need to do more than pull lines out of a webpage retrieved using `curl`.

Comment: What you're trying to do is "screen scraping".  I assume that sooner or later you'll need something more general than "the text between 'strong'".  Since you put "Perl" in your tags, I would encourage you to look at [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/WWW-Mechanize-1.54/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm).  Otherwise, look here: [Linux - grep regex to pull out a string between two known strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850031/grep-regex-to-pull-out-a-string-between-two-known-strings).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Perl regex's look-behind and look-ahead feature in grep. It should be simpler than using awk.

```
grep -oP "(?<=<strong>).*?(?=</strong>)" file
```

Output:

```
Target1NoSpaces
Target2 With Spaces
```

Add:

This implementation of Perl's regex's multi-matching in Ruby could match values in multiple lines:

```
ruby -e 'File.read(ARGV.shift).scan(/(?<=<strong>).*?(?=<\/strong>)/m).each{|e| puts "----------"; puts e;}' file
```

Input:

```
<strong>Target
A
B
C
</strong><strong>Target D</strong><strong>Target E</strong>
```

Output:

```
----------
Target
A
B
C
----------
Target D
----------
Target E
```

Comment: +1 good approach if the tag doesn't split over multiple lines.

Comment: This works perfectly.  The tags are on a single line and are words or a collection of two/three words.  The output is regular and will always be the same so an approach that does anything more is overkill.  I like the awk and perl implementations and will tuck those away for future use.  Thanks, all for elevating my knowledge!

Comment: @sudo_O Perl regex's multi-line feature could actually be used for that. I added a concept implementation of it in Ruby. Michael J: Welcome :)

Answer (score 14):

Try [`pup`](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup), a command line tool for processing HTML. For example:

```
$ pup 'strong text{}' < file.html 
Target1NoSpaces
Target2 With Spaces
```

---

To search via XPath, try [`xpup`](https://github.com/ericchiang/xpup).

Alternatively, for a  well-formed HTML/XML document, try [`html-xml-utils`](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/).

Comment: Thanks for this tip!  I still follow this thread to stay up to date on simple CLI parsing.  Thanks to your answer, TIL about `pup`! :D

Comment: Wow! To test it without polluting your local environment:

1. `docker pull golang`
2. `docker run --rm -it golang`
3. `go install github.com/ericchiang/pup@latest`
4. `curl -s https://example.com | pup "body h1"`

With this you'll create an autodestroyable container, get `pup` into it and see it working by getting the `<h1>` of the canonical example page.

Answer (score 7):

One way using `mojolicious` and its `DOM` parser:

```
perl -Mojo -E '
    g("http://your.web")
    ->dom
    ->find("strong")
    ->each( sub { if ( $t = shift->text ) { say $t } } )'
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution using [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)

```
xml sel -t -v //strong input.html
```

Answer (score 3):

[Trying to parse HTML without a real HTML parser is a bad idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) Having said that, here is a very quick and dirty solution *to the specific example you provided.* It will not work when there is more than one `<strong>` tag on a line, when the tag runs over more than one line, etc.

```
awk -F '<strong>|</strong>' '/<strong>/ {print $2}' filename
```

Answer (score 3):

You never need `grep` with `awk` and the field separator doesn't have to be whitespace:

```
$ awk -F'<|>'  '/strong/{print $3}' file
Target1NoSpaces
Target2 With Spaces
```

You should really use a proper parser for this however.

Comment: That could match any text with `strong` in it. Or just a newline if no field was found.

Comment: @konsolebox if we get into the pit falls of parsing html with `awk` we could be here a while. I simply wanted to demonstrate the use in my point, the OP can filter/make more robust as appropriate or take my suggestion and use a proper html parser.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged perl

```
perl -ne 'if(/(?:<strong>)(.*)(?:<\/strong>)/){print $1."\n";}' input.html
```

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised no one mensions W3C [HTML-XML-utils](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/README)

```sh
curl -Ss https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746957/parsing-html-on-the-command-line-how-to-capture-text-in-strong-strong |
  hxnormalize -x |
  hxselect -s '\n' strong
```

output:

```
<strong class="fc-black-750 mb6">Stack Overflow
                    for Teams</strong>
<strong>Teams</strong>
```

To capture only content:

```sh
curl -Ss https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746957/parsing-html-on-the-command-line-how-to-capture-text-in-strong-strong |
  hxnormalize -x |
  hxselect -s '\n' -c strong
```

```
Stack Overflow
                    for Teams
Teams
```