# How to specify and extract html element by curl

Tags: linux, curl, command

when I tried to curl some pages.

`curl http://test.com`

I can get like following result

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
  <dl>
    <dd> 10 times </dd>
  </dl>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my desired result is like simply `10 times`..

Are there any good way to achieve this ?

If someone has opinion please let me know

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing HTML on the command line; How to capture text in <strong></strong>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746957/parsing-html-on-the-command-line-how-to-capture-text-in-strong-strong)

Comment: Please search "curl xpath bash", plenty of results...

Comment: Preferably, use one the answers in the linked post that use a proper HTML parser (preferred over using regex). The same method can be used for other tags.

Answer (score 2):

If you are are unable to use a html parser for what ever reason, for your given simple html example, you could use:

```
 curl http://test.com | sed -rn 's@(^.*<dd>)(.*)(</dd>)@\2@p'
```

Redirect the output of the curl command into sed and enable regular expression interpretation with -r or -E. Split the lines into three sections and substitute the line for the second section only, printing the result.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue but i need to extract selected option value YES or NO from CURL HTML response.

```
<td valign=top>
    <select name="active">
          <option selected value="false">No</option>
          <option  value="true">Yes</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

CURL command with auth params to get selected option and it's value.

```
curl -d ".username=Jhon" -d ".password=123456" "https://test.com/" | grep "option selected" | tail -1 | awk -F'<|>'  '/option/{print $3}'
```

You can use `tail` or `head` if there is multiple select option to get desired  HTML element

Answer (score 0):

```
$ curl ... | awk -F' *<[/]?dd> *' 'NF>1{print $2}'
$ curl ... | awk  'match($0,"<dd> *(.*) *</dd>",a){print a[1]}'
10 times
```